# Would a contingency $\chi^2$ test be useful in this case?

Tags: chi-squared-test, survival, methodology, mortality

I am looking at mortality of caterpillars who were reared on different diets. I have the total number of caterpillars on each diet on the first day of observation, and then again on the final day of observation. Here is an example of my data where the numbers represent the number of individuals:

```
Diet 1:
First day:3997
Final Day:2435

Diet 2
First day:1876
Final day:1316
```

I want to determine if there was a significant loss in individuals between the two treatments.

**Question:** Would a contingency $\chi^2$ test work?

Comment: Do you know the numbers for each intermediate day?

Comment: Yes, I have the # of individuals for each day of observation, but I don't need a really sophisticated test. This isn't a main finding; it's just something that should help me in my defense regarding caterpillar performance, so I opted for first day and final day only.

Comment: Bump************